# Scrape page after onload JS DOM injection

Tags: javascript, dom, node.js, web-scraping

I'm building a scraper that gets main images (based on `Content-Length` right now) from a page. It goes through all `<img>` elements and makes a `HEAD` request. But certain pages, esp. mobile, have images inserted after page load. Any ideas on how to tackle this?

I'm using `node.js`.

Comment: You'd have to run the relevant JS on your server to replicate what those pages are doing.

Comment: @MarcB: How do I run the relevant JS on my server? Is there a library or would I been writing this myself? I'm using [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure that it solves your problem, but you could look into using [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), as it can fetch and execute the scripts in a page, and gives you a DOM on the serverside. Something like:

```
var request = require('request'),
    jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;

request(url, function(err, response, body) {
  if(err) return console.error(err);

  var doc = jsdom(body, null, {
    FetchExternalResources: ['script', 'img']
  });
  var window = doc.createWindow();

  var images = doc.getElementsByTagName('img');
});
```

Comment: What can I say, I'm just trying to help. The above works for me, fetching a page which adds `img` tags dynamically.

Comment: I'm sure it does work and thanks for sharing this. I was using this `jsdom` earlier and it used to break on a lot of sites with not perfect HTML. So, for me, `jsdom` is not an option, sorry!

Comment: Simulating the DOM will often be quirky. That is why I recommend PhantomJS which is an actual WebKit browser instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/). It "is a headless WebKit with JavaScript API". Think of it like a whole browser you can control via a JavaScript API. As it is a browser it will fully execute the pages and then you can scrape them.

It is somewhat *similar* to Node.js, but is really a full browser where your scripts have full access to the DOM of the page you have it pull down. So it is *much* easier to to 'scrape' a page intelligently by accessing the DOM using something like jQuery, instead of just accessing raw HTML.

Here is an example on [DOM manipulation](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart#DOM_Manipulation)

Comment: That sounds interesting but it may just be too much of an overkill. But thanks. :)